# Vite vue 3 inline src url load for assets folder

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vite

How can dynamic inline load images from assets in vite + vue3 ?

```
<img :src="new URL(`@/assets/${i.image}`, import.meta.url).href" />
```

return error:

> Error parsing JavaScript expression: import.meta may appear only with
> 'sourceType: "module"' (1:38)

Answer (score 0):

You will need extract the logic into a helper function in the script block

```
function getImageUrl(name) {
  return new URL(`../assets/${name}`, import.meta.url).href
}


<img :src="getImageUrl(i.image)" />
```

note that short hands `@assets` also doesn't work, need use relative urls.

source: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url